# Fast lexicon lookup with phrases and stemming in python

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

I'm building a text classifier in python and I have a list of key phrases for each class. For example the classes can be "travel" and "science" and lists could contain:

- travel: "New York", "South Korea", "Seoul", etc.
- science: "scientist", "chemical", etc.

I'm looking for the best way to match phrases from such lists in python.

For instance, the result for the document:

> A famous scientist traveled from New York to Seoul, South Korea

should be:
"science": 1
"travel": 3

Even if the "in" operator for strings is well optimized, there are a few situations which should be handled as well:

- word boundaries: at some point I can have "to" in the dictionary, and wouldn't want to match "to" in "tomorrow". Tokenization would work in this case, but some custom logic would be required for phrases, maybe sub-list lookup in the list of tokens.
- stemming: "scientists discovered" should also be matched when there is "scientist discover" in the list

Is there a python library which could handle this efficiently? If I need to implement it from scratch, what would be the best way to handle the above issues in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is phrasal search on stems. It's text mining
task I think and is implemented in search engines.

First you need `tokenize` and `stemmer` functions. Tokenize can be
as simple as:

```
def tokenize(string):
    return fiter(lambda x: len(x) < 1, remove_punctuation(string).split())
```

There is various stemmers on pypi.

You will end up with a function like the following:

```
def preprocess(string):
    return [stemmer(word) for word in tokenize(string)]
```

Then the function you are looking for looks like the following:

```
from collections import Counter


def count(dictionary, phrase):
    counter = Count()
    phrase = preprocess(phrase)
    for topic, string in dictionary.items():
        stems = preprocess(string)
        indices = find(phrase, stem[0])
        for index in indices:
            found = True
            for stem in stems[1:]:
                if phrase[index + 1] == stem:
                   continue
                else:
                   found = False
                   break
            if found:
               counter[topic] +=1
    return counter
```

The `dictionary` variable  contains the following information:

- travel: "New York", "South Korea", "Seoul", etc.
- science: "scientist", "chemical", etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a simple solution is to use dictionary comprehension:

```
s = "A famous scientist traveled from New York to Seoul, South Korea"
d = {"travel":["New York", "South Korea", "Seoul"], "science": ["scientist", "chemical"]}
final_results = {a:sum(i in s for i in b) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'science': 1, 'travel': 3}
```

Comment: quite elegant, but doesn't solve the two questions - word boundaries and stemming of n-grams